# NoMethodError in Welcome#show

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, nomethoderror

Here is the error I am getting:

[image: error]

Background:

I am trying to display a button based on whether an action is complete or not. Here is my code

```
<% if @courses_user.complete! %>
  <%= link_to "Completed", course, class: "block text-lg w-full text-center text-white px-4 py-2 bg-green hover:bg-green-dark border-2 border-green-dark leading-none no-underline" %>
<% else %>
  <%= link_to "View Modules", course, class: "block text-lg w-full text-center text-grey-dark hover:text-darker px-4 py-2 border-2 border-grey leading-none no-underline hover:border-2 hover:border-grey-dark" %>
<% end %>
```

In my courses_user model, I have

```
class CoursesUser < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :course
  belongs_to :user

  has_many :course_modules_users

  def completed!
    self.update_attributes(complete: true)
  end
end
```

and in the welcomeController I have

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @courses = Course.all.order(created_at: :asc)
    @courses_user = CoursesUser.all
  end
end
```

But I'm getting a NoMethodError, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have defined `@courses_user = CoursesUser.all`, so its a **collection** not a single object. And you **can't call** `complete!` on a collection, so is the error.

**Solution:**

Iterate through `@courses_user` and call `complete!` on each instance like so

```
<% @courses_user.each do |cu| %>
  <% if cu.complete! %>
    <%= link_to "Completed", course, class: "block text-lg w-full text-center text-white px-4 py-2 bg-green hover:bg-green-dark border-2 border-green-dark leading-none no-underline" %>
  <% else %>
    <%= link_to "View Modules", course, class: "block text-lg w-full text-center text-grey-dark hover:text-darker px-4 py-2 border-2 border-grey leading-none no-underline hover:border-2 hover:border-grey-dark" %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**Note:**

To avoid another potential error, you should change `complete!` to `completed!` as there is no method as `complete!` in your `CoursesUser` model.

So the final code would be

```
<% @courses_user.each do |cu| %>
  <% if cu.completed! %>
    <%= link_to "Completed", course, class: "block text-lg w-full text-center text-white px-4 py-2 bg-green hover:bg-green-dark border-2 border-green-dark leading-none no-underline" %>
  <% else %>
    <%= link_to "View Modules", course, class: "block text-lg w-full text-center text-grey-dark hover:text-darker px-4 py-2 border-2 border-grey leading-none no-underline hover:border-2 hover:border-grey-dark" %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Oh ok, error on my part I'm updating the attribute, I only want to check whether it's complete or not, updating the attribute I can use elsewhere but for this page, I only want to check if the course is marked as complete or not.

Comment: Yes but in the model it have https://gyazo.com/1778c52fd0d8a66da1d386b1bb2af4ac `self.update_attribute` this I can use elsewhere, but I want to check whether it's marked as true or not as it's marking all courses as complete now

Comment: @B.J.B If you want to check whether a course is complete, then try `<% if cu.complete? %>`